# Using the MongoDB C# Driver: Wrapped or Un-Wrapped?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am building some update statements with the MongoDB C# driver. [The C# API](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/) includes both Wrapped and "Un-Wrapped" methods in the `Builder` namespace.

On the surface, it appears that these differ by generics and not having to use a [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) wrapper. However, both method types allow me to pass in a non-Bson-Wrapped parameter. Is there a functional difference between the two?

For example (using driver v1.2), here are two uses of `Update.Set`:

```cs
var myCollection = database.GetCollection<MyObject>(typeof(MyObject).Name);

myCollection.Update(
  Query.EQ( "_id", myId ),
  Update.Set( "Message", "My message text"));

// And now the same call with "Wrapped" method
myCollection.Update(
  Query.EQ( "_id", myId ),
  Update.SetWrapped( "Message", "My message text"));
```

What is the difference between these two calls? If only syntactic sugar - why the need for a Wrapped version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference when you set a string value. Wrapped methods are needed when you work with complex types: classes, lists, etc (which is not `BsonValue`). They just correctly convert the objects to BsonValue type.

Small example:

With Set you can't do following:

```
var item = new MyDemo();
Update.Set("Item", item)
```

You have to use Wrapped method or ToBsonDocument() extention:

```
var item = new MyDemo();
Update.SetWrapped("Item", item)
```

That's it!

One note, the driver and most pieces around mongodb are open source. So it isn't a big deal to [look at](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Builders/UpdateBuilder.cs) :)