# Update complex types without wrapping

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When writing new documents or updating existing ones, the mongodb-c-sharp-driver outputs generic bson/json for non-primitive types

```
"myList" : [
    {"value" : "..."},
    {"value" : "..."}
]
```

When using the `Update.Set()` statement however, the driver wraps the actual data with type info

```
"myList" : {
    "_t" : "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Models.MyModel, Common]]",
    "_v" : [
        {"value" : "..."},
        {"value" : "..."}
    ]
}
```

I want to avoid this wrapping, since the same dataset is potentially used by other drivers/languages in a distributed environment.

Is the only way to achieve that to fetch the entire document, update and write back?

Related old questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732663/bsonvalue-and-custom-classes-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863238/using-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-wrapped-or-un-wrapped) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/9E8cWs7fVIs).

**UPDATE**

This code triggers the type wrappers

```
public void Set(ObjectId id, string name, object value)
{
    var query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
    var update = Update.Set(name, value.ToBsonDocument());
    _collection.Update(query, update);
}
```

And here's a generic method I came up with. It is able to set primitive types as well as complex types without type info:

```
public void Set<T>(ObjectId id, string name, T value)
{
    var query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
    var update = Update.Set(name, ConvertToBsonValue<T>(value));
    _collection.Update(query, update);
}

public BsonValue ConvertToBsonValue<T>(T value)
{
    try
    {
        return BsonValue.Create(value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return value.ToBsonDocument<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could provide your code, perhaps we could help you fix it.

Comment: @CraigWilson Please see the update. I think that solves it since nominal type and actual type are the same and known. Is that correct or can it be done better? In the source code I spotted something for custom converters, but haven't looked deeper, yet. The reason I'm doing this is to share basic operations between many repository classes that handle different complex types. Thanks!

Comment: As I still don't have the code that is causing the problems, I couldn't tell you if this solves your problem. I know that you are using exceptions as control flow here, and that is not good. If you'd like to provide the actual code that is causing problems, I'd happy to take a look.

Comment: Updated again with what doesn't work and what works. The exception handler lets `BsonValue.Create` and `BsonTypeMapper.MapToBsonValue` run their compatibility checks. I'd be happy if there's a more elegant way without repeating the quite long code you wrote already ;) E.g. `Type.IsPrimitive` means `DateTime` will run as `.ToBsonDocument` instead of `BsonValue.Create`

Comment: Oh, you are using an object. Yeah... there isn't much we can do with an object. Working with a typed API generally implies that you know what the types are. Since you are using object, the only possible way we could round-trip that value would be to use a discriminator. You'll either need to live with your solution, or refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Generics instead of objects, the conversion to BsonValue is not necessary.